# Can I directly run compiled code in windows?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

In [this](https://godbolt.org/z/dGvW9z) site, wrote a simple C code and got its assembly code: (x86-64 gcc 10.2)

```
#include<stdio.h>
// Type your code here, or load an example.
int main() {
    int a=5, b=5;
    int c = a+b;
    return 0;
}
```

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 5
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 5
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        add     eax, edx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], eax
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

If I copy the above assembly code and paste it in notepad, can I somehow run it in windows to get the same expected output as if I ran the above C code? If I can, how should I do it.

Comment: What you got is the assembly source.  Run that through an assembler, and you'll have your executable.  Or, just use an ordinary C compiler on the original C code, which will also get you an executable.

Comment: CPUs run binary machine code, not asm text source.  If you *assemble* this into a `.obj` and link it just like a C compiler would have, then yes.

Comment: You might be interested in the [EICAR test file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EICAR_test_file) entry on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a text editor like notepad to write a binary file, since text editors normally strip out bytes that do not represent printable characters. You would have to use a hex editor, or some other editor that is intended for binary files.

Secondly, unless you're writing a *very basic* executable file format ([like the .COM file format for DOS](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080324-00/?p=23033)), you would have to do more than just write the machine code for the intended entry point of your program. EXE and ELF executables consist of a header, relocations, text, data, resources, etc. not just machine code.

Comment: Also, you can't use a function that ends with `ret` as your process entry point (again unless it's a DOS `.com` where the stack pointer on entry points at code that will exit the process).

Answer (score 2):

You need to assemble it into an object file, and either link it with a loader (like the CRT) or run as-is as a `.com` file (which isn't supported under Windows, that's a DOS thing).

Comment: To clarify, it isn't supported under 64-bit Windows, 32-bit Windows can run DOS just fine (NTVDM)